# ember-simple-auth update data in session

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I have the following code:

```
changeUsername: function(){
    var _this = this;
    this.store.findById('user', this.session.get('user.id')).then(function(user){
        user.set('username', _this.get('newUsername'));
        user.save();

        _this.session.set('user.username', _this.get('newUsername'));
        _this.session.persist();
    });
}
```

As you can see - I am persisting to the ember simple auth session a user object which I want to update in this method.

Calling persist on the session doesn't do the trick.

I have also tried:

```
_this.session.store.set('user.username', _this.get('newUsername'));
_this.session.store.save();
```

Which didn't work either.

How can I update the user object on the session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have extended or reopened the simple auth session with a method of user with a computed property on userId the answer would be

```
  var _this = this;
  if(!Ember.isEmpty(this.get('session.content.userId'))) {
     this.get('session.user').then(function(user){
       user.set('username', _this.get('newUsername'));
       user.save();
     });
  }
```

and your template would use `{{ session.user.username }}`